# How to check if String has a Dot, but not in front or in the end?

Tags: java, eclipse, nachos

I'm currently practicing for my Java Practicum Exam, most importantly NachOS, here is my trouble right now. I'm stuck at developing this right now

> Ask the user to input file name. The file name must contain dot (‘.’). Dot must not be in front of or in the end of the file name.

So far I've created the code like this

```
do {
        cs.write("Name: ");
        name = cs.read();
        Format = name.split(".");
    } while (Format.length!=1);
```

and the problem is that it still won't validate dot, even if I've typed the input "important.docx" for the example. can you tell why this happens and how I should solve this?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that split works but it's not the best way to check for the presence of a character in a string, why are you splitting by `-` if you need to check for the presence of `.`?

Comment: See [`name.indexOf('.')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`name.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--).

Comment: `split(".")` will not work, since `.` is a special character in a regex.

Comment: Is ".a.b." a legal name? It contains a dot which is not in the front of nor in the end of the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, Java has methods for that:

```
private static boolean validFileName(final String name) {
    return name.contains(".") && !name.startsWith(".") && !name.endsWith(".");
}
```